# setting class properties from array

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-studio, linked-list

How can I access the get and set method of a class that is inside an array as objects?

Ex:

Dog.cs

```
Class Dog{
int id;
string name;

public void setid(int newid){
    id=newid;
}
public void setname(string newname){
    name=newname;
}

public int getid() { return id; }

public string getname() { return name; }}
```

main.cs

```
main(){

public LinkedList<Object> dogs = new LinkedList<Object>();

public void onCreate(){
    Dog newDog = new Dog();

    newDog.setid((int) 1);
    newDog.setname((string) "Doggy");

    dogs.add(newDog);
}

public void LoadEvent(){

    // I want to get the dog's values like this

    string itsname = dogs.get(0).getname();

}}
```

I want to access the get and set methods that I write in the dog.class but I can't access those because I put the class inside an array as an object. please tell me how can this be done or is there any other methods of doing this.

please help me

super thanks!

Comment: Please put your comment as answer so that I can mark it also, can you please give me more detail about parametrizing the class. Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options:

1 (bad): cast returned `Object` to required type before accessing its member:

```
String name = ((Dog)dogs.get(0)).getName();
```

2 (better one): parametrize your list by `Dog`, so instances could be operated without casting:

```
List<Dog> dogs = new LinkedList<>(); // by <Dog> we say, that list will contain `Dog` instances
// ...
String name = dogs.get(0).getName();
```

Besides, why `LinkedList`? It is perfect for stacks and queues, not random-access lists. I suppose `ArrayList` in your case would be much better.

Comment: Super thanks, I've used the Bad one because of some bug in my android studio where the adding a class in the list will make all the elements value the same.

Answer (score 0):

If you are confident all of the objects in the array are Dogs, then cast them when you go to access the property:

```
String itsname = ((Dog)dogs.get(0)).getName();
```

If you're not confident, then check it:

```
String itsName = null;
if (dogs.get(0) instanceof Dog.class) {
  itsName = (Dog)dogs.get(0).getName();
}
```

Otherwise, I recommend asserting that the object is full of Dogs before hand so you don't have to deal with this:

```
public LinkedList<Dog> dogs = new LinkedList<Dog>();
```